# What happens if increase pod cpu limit?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, cpu

When I deployed something to K8s, the pods used a lot of CPU to stand up and then go back to normal.

In the as is structure, my limit cpu value was 1 core, and these pods were up using about 0.9 core CPU, and then they went down to very little values and remained stable.

When I increased the limit cpu value to 2 cores, the pods stood up from 0.8 and there was no throttle. But I don't understand how to explain it and what caused it.

I want to understand the reason for this and configure exactly how I should set the limit cpu value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.